Testing Quarkus Panache.withTransaction: ow to do without DB on test profile?
I am working on a Quarkus project with Entities (PanacheEntityBase).
From one of my exposed endpoint I am calling Panache.withTransaction() and within the .invoke() I am updating my entity:
return Panache.withTransaction(() ->
                    MyEntity.findMyEntity()
                      .invoke((Entity myEntity) -> {
                               myEntity.property1 = "a";
                              }
                            )
            );

All works perfectly well in PRD, but I cannot make tests working, using    io.restassured.RestAssured, due to a Mutiny.SessionFactory bean not found error.
@Test
@RunOnVertxContext
void should_return_204() {
    MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();

    PanacheMock.mock(MyEntity.class);
    Mockito.when(MyEntity.findMyEntity())
            .thenReturn(Uni.createFrom().item(myEntity));

    given()
            .when()
            .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
            .body(body)
            .patch("my-entity")
            .then()
            .statusCode(HttpStatus.SC_NO_CONTENT);
}

On my test profile (application.yml) I have the hibernate ORM disabled, since I don’t have a DB in our Jenkins pipeline.
Can you advise what are the best practices to run tests in this context? How to test the outcome of what’s happening in invoke?
Thanks
